# Weird output of simple expression in C, why?

Tags: c++, c, turbo-c++

I am using TurboC++. I write the following expression which is not resulting in proper evaluation, am I missing some concept behind it?

```
int c=300*300/300;
printf("%d",c);
```

The output is

> 81

Why?

Comment: What is `sizeof(int)`?

Comment: It was just that I typed 'C' instead of 'c' while asking the question. I have made the edit. It's 'c' in lower case itself.

Comment: TurboC++ is a C++ compiler. You might want to tag c++ instead of c (it's just a detail, but it's confusing).

Comment: It is 2 byte. I am using DosBox.

Comment: Is this the whole code ?

Comment: So, if `sizeof(int) == 2`, then what is `INT_MAX`?

Comment: I have not written the whole code its Just a main() function which is holding the above  code, that's it.

Comment: @Vultrao the TC++ package includes a C compiler and a C++ compiler

Comment: It might be a duplicated question but thanks to all for giving time. Yes @Mohit even I don't expect myself to miss such small concepts about data types.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
300*300 is 90000.
```

Assuming int is 16bit, you have overflowed.

The overflow wraps around, giving you: `24464`.

```
24465/300 = 81.55
```

*Do not rely on this. It is undefined behavior.*

Comment: Does that mean if I run the above program on gcc then the output would be correct? Because there the size of int is 4byte or 32bit.

Comment: Yes, but you would be better to change your method rather than tools.

Comment: Sure I will. Thanks I missed the concept of integer range.

Comment: Just a quick note: the integer size with gcc is not necessarily 4 bytes, this depends on the platform. If you want integers with a specific size, use the types from `stdint.h`, e.g. `int32_t`. (These may not exist with Turbo C++ as it is quite old.)

Comment: @Jack thanks ! This is more effective approach to most problems in C, I tried in on CPPDroid and it works good,thanks again for this.

Comment: @Milind it's a good idea in general to run your code on many different compilers, it can help catch errors you make due to faulty assumptions. One common faulty assumption is that int is 32 bit ; as you see here it can be 16, and on other systems it can be 64.

Comment: @Matt yes this was indeed very helpful, such small concepts makes a better progarmmer.

Comment: loooooool 16 bit `int`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Eh?

Answer (score 9):

The evaluation of 300 * 300 / 300 happens from left to right.

300 * 300 overflows a 16 bit signed integral type (an `int` in Turbo C++ is 16 bit). As the computation will take place in signed arithmetic, **the result is undefined**.

What's happening is 300 * 300 is wrapping round to give you 24464. (24464 + 32768 + 32768 = 90000).

24464 / 300 is 81 in integer division.

Comment: The type of an expression is based on the type of its operands - not their values. `int` multiplied by `int` gives `int` regardless of the values of the ints.